# Statistics/Combinations Algorithm

Tags: math, recursion, statistics, combinations

I was trying to code for the following requirement, but then figured there could be a formula for this. Here goes.

For a set of N elements, I want to calculate the number of un-ordered sets whose maximum size is S. I have found [formulas](https://www3.nd.edu/~dgalvin1/10120/10120_S16/Topic07_6p7_Galvin.pdf) for where S is a fixed value (not a maximum value) but not for my requirement.

For 9*3 (N*S) = 12 I have drawn the following solution tree;

```
// dashes are set separators
@@@--@@@--@@@
@@@--@@@--@@--@
@@@--@@@--@--@--@
@@@--@@--@@--@@
@@@--@@--@@--@--@
@@@--@@--@--@--@--@
@@@--@--@--@--@--@--@
@@--@@--@@--@@--@
@@--@@--@@--@--@--@
@@--@@--@--@--@--@--@
@@--@--@--@--@--@--@--@
@--@--@--@--@--@--@--@--@
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions about **math** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Riyaz, if you want a closed formula rather than an algorithm to calculate it, you should definitely go to the Math Stack Exchange. What you are looking for is probably should be called [Partitions of `N` with biggest addend up to `S`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory))

Comment: Apologies if Q inappropriate.  When I saw the tags available, thought this level was acceptable. Thanks @SergGr. If anyone is interested, the solution is m(3m-1)/2 where m = {1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,...}

Comment: How might solution for two-argument problem contain only one parameter?

Comment: @MBo you're right. My comment was incomplete. I don't have the link right now, but it gives the coefficients to some series which in tern gives the solution. But no need, your observation is brilliant. I'll try that one.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate number of sets using simple observation:

```
 F(N,S) = F(N-1,1)+F(N-2,2)+...+F(N-S,S)
```

number of sets with max set power=1 +  number of sets with max set power=2 and so on. Use recursion or fill a table (dynamic programming), using some border conditions like `F(1,1)=1`